# Services on Multi-Primary on different networks

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

Could be very simple for someone to answer this.

How do you access services discovered in multi primary cluster environment

I have service webappsvc running on Cluster1 and unless I create webappsvc on cluster2 I'm not able to access the webappsvc.Cluster1 service from Cluster2. I can see the endpoint is discovered in Cluster2 for the service webappsvc.Cluster1 but can't really access it without creating identical service in Cluster2.

My query is if the service is discovered then it should be accessible directly through discovered ep? or I need to create ServiceEntry in Cluster2 ?

Thanks in advance

Expecting to access webappsvc.Cluster1 service from Cluster2.